# Install Gnome3 on FreeBSD 12

Tags: gnome, freebsd

According to the [FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/), Gnome can be installed as follows.

```
pkg install gnome3
```

This command results in the following error.

```
pkg: No packages available to install matching 'gnome3'
have been found in the repositories.
```

I attempted the following command to determine which package I need to install.

```
pkg search gnome
```

This yielded 155 results but I am not certain which one to use.

I am using FreeBSD 12.

I would rather not use the ports collection. I prefer to use pre-built binary packages.

Answer (score 3):

There is a meta-port for [Gnome 3](https://www.freshports.org/x11/gnome3/). It is available on older systems:

```
$ uname -r
11.1-RELEASE
$ pkg -v
1.10.5
$ pkg search gnome3
gnome3-3.18.0_1                "meta-port" for the GNOME 3 integrated X11 desktop
gnome3-lite-3.18.0_1           The "meta-port" of the GNOME desktop slimmed down for only the basics
libproxy-gnome3-0.4.12         GSettings-based configuration plug-in for libproxy
pinentry-gnome3-1.1.0          GNOME 3 version of the GnuPG password dialog
```

If you cannot find it the first thing to try is to update the index:

```
sudo pkg update
```

You can also look online to see what binary packages are actually built:

```
https://pkg.freebsd.org/
```

You are using 12.0 which is only [2 days old](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/12.0R/schedule.html). They might not be done building all the binary packages yet. If it is a new install then maybe consider using 11.2 and then upgrade a little later.

So update to make sure. If it is still not there - then build yourself - or simply wait.

I am not sure how updated the [FreeBSD Gnome](https://www.freebsd.org/gnome/) page is but it could be worth tracking that.

That is what I would recommend. If you cannot live with that - then you can use the old previously built packages. Find and download the package as a `.txz` file on https://pkg.freebsd.org/. I found [gnome3-3.18.0.txz](https://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/release_1/All/gnome3-3.18.0.txz) and [gnome3-lite-3.18.0_1.txz](https://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:amd64/release_1/All/gnome3-lite-3.18.0_1.txz) for [AMD64](https://www.freebsd.org/platforms/amd64.html)

Then you can do:

```
pkg add <pkgname.txz>
```

Be sure to check consistency afterwards using `pkg check -d` and `pkg check -B`.

I will however only recommend this approach for simpler packages than Gnome. But the option is there...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pkg install gnome-desktop`. Worked on my end. It seems that meta package for gnome desktop has changed in this release.

Comment: Did you not install something else? If you look at the [Freshports](https://www.freshports.org/x11/gnome-desktop/) description it says: "This is a collection of APIs.". That is a strange description then. Would be nice if you could confirm. And the [Gnome 3](https://www.freshports.org/x11/gnome3/) port is still there.

Comment: No, I've figured this out while I downloaded ports and searched for gnome-specific ports.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to modify pkgng to point at the freebsd repo. but before that make a back up of FreeBSD.conf.

Actually you are going to change repository from

url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/quarterly" to

url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest".

nano /etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf:

```
FreeBSD: {
    url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest"
    Mirror_type: "srv",
    enabled: yes
 }
```